# morphology and ill-formed sentences

Tags: morphology

Can we say that ungrammatical strings are still part of the English language? Like for example Joe sleep not last night.

Comment: That depends entirely on your criterion for "part of the English language". Linguistics is not set theory. As [Jim McCawley](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) put it, "The relation between having a language and a set of sentences  is not unlike the relation between having a car and a set of  trips to the supermarket."

Comment: No. -----------

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, maybe not.

It sounds like you're familiar with the computer science definition of a "language" as a set of strings (where a "string" is an ordered sequence of characters, and a "character" is an element of an arbitrary but pre-defined set called the "alphabet"). But in linguistics, it's never quite that clear-cut.

For example, consider the sentence "I ain't got nothing". Would you consider this sentence part of the English language, or not? Many native speakers would say yes, but many other native speakers would say no. There are dialects of English where this sentence would be immediately accepted as grammatical, and other dialects where it would be immediately rejected.

Sort of like "word", "language" is one of those terms that comes up all the time in linguistics, even though it doesn't have any widely-accepted rigorous definition. The whole idea of discrete "languages" breaks down the moment you look at dialect continua—compare the languages spoken all across Italy and you won't be able to draw hard lines anywhere. But we still use it anyway, just because it's an extremely useful model in most circumstances.

In this case, no native English speaker I know would produce that sentence. However, every native English speaker I know would understand the meaning perfectly. Does that make it a part of the English language? Well, that's up to you and the definitions you decide to use.

P.S. The main error in your sentence is syntactic, not morphological. For a pure morphology error, try something like *"Alex sleep" (instead of "Alex sleep**s**").

Comment: That example is not *pure* morphology: the error is incorrect agreement, which is syntax. "d-sleep" is pure morphology (prefixing a suffix).

Comment: @user6726 I'd call it a morphology error, because what's happening is "the syntax says you need `-∅` but you actually have `-s`". In other words, the syntax is fine, but the morphology's not doing what the syntax says.

Comment: It was just an example, what matters the most is the consideration in the English language. However, very clear explanations. It is of great help.